# Find Combinations of fibonacci values to approximate a target value given $F(A,B,C,D) = (A + B + C) / D$

Tags: approximation-algorithms, optimization, combinatorics

I am able to solve this using brute force but curious if there is a better approach.

Given the function $F(A,B,C,D) = (A + B + C) / D$ where each variable is in the first 7 distinct values of the Fibonacci sequence, i.e. $[1,2,3,5,8,13,21]$,determine the values which most closely approximate any given target value.

the values can be repetitions, so $[1,1,1,1]$ is a valid combination.

Comment: For 7 values it's quite likely brute-force will be better in practice than anything else, particularly if you precalculate all possible values and then you can do a binary search. Are you interested in solutions for the first $N$ fibonacci values?

Comment: Yes in practice you're right and I get a solution in under a second, this is more of a curiosity thing if there's a more generalized approach if I were to add an arbitrary number of variables in the numerator or extend the domain to an arbitrary number of fibonacci values.

Comment: This is not a research-level question. I am not sure where curiosity questions belong, maybe on https://cs.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score -1):

If we iterate over all possible values for $D$, we want to calculate for each the maximum $n \leq xD$ which is a sum of three Fibonacci numbers, and the minimum such $n \geq xD$. It isn't hard to see that a number can be represented as a sum of three Fibonacci numbers iff its Zeckendorf representation has at most 3 ones. Since lexicographical order on the Zeckendorf representations (assuming they are padded with zeros to be the same length) is the same a the normal order of integers, so once we find the Zechendorf representation of $\lfloor xD \rfloor$ we can find the biggest string less than it with no two consecutive zeros and at most three 1s, and that will be our first $n$, and then we can do something similar for $\lceil xD \rceil$ and for bigger values.

I believe this algorithm can be implemented in $O(n^2)$, but this is tricky because the Fibonacci numbers have length of $O(n)$ bits.